# "Row Not Found or Changed" Error Pops Up Randomly

Tags: c#, submitchanges

When I run

DB.SubmitChanges();

I occasionally get an error that reads: "Row not found or changed".
The reason why this error bugs me so much is because there will always a row that should be found for this query, and changes are only made if there are new changes to make.

I can't seem to figure out why this error pops up
Are there some common reasons why this error shows up that I can try to find in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be 2 reasons:

- the Row was deleted
- the row was changed by another client

Both are due to concurrency, the first thing to check is if this could indeed be a multi-user issue.

Comment: Is it good practice to define many changes and have one DB.SubmitChanges(); or define many changes and have one DB.SubmitChanges(); after each change defined?

Comment: It depends (on your business requirements). Batching the changes will be more efficient but also increases the likelihood another process made changes. But you will have to deal with that anyhow.